# PHP, MySQL - login\logout issue, login only after second attempt

Tags: php, mysql, session, cookies

I have a very strange logout issue.

The flow of the work:

1. Log in page
2. Main view (choosing a task)
3. Task initialization that prepares the task in the background
4. Task view (submitting some answer and clicking on submit)
5. updates in the DB.  initialization of the next line (go to number 3)

I am using Session and cookies in order to login.

The problem occurs only one time after logout the user tries to login.
He succeffully reaches his Main view (different for each user)
Successfully choose a task, go to the task view, enters submit.
Then instead of the next page he receives "log out, please login" statement, meaning that my "checkUser" didnt find a session or a cookie and kicked him out.
When he makes the login the next time, everything is working correctly.

I dont understand where to begin to look for this issue.

My login page relevant code:

```
session_start();
 $error_msg = "";
//Do you have Session or cookies?
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && isset( $_SESSION['user_role'])) 
{
    If ($_SESSION['user_role']=='DM')
        header('Location: DMView.php');
    else if ($_SESSION['user_role']=='Vendor')
        header('Location: VendorView.php');
    exit;
}
 //If you dont - Did you enter sumbit?
 if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && isset($_POST['submit'])) 
 {
      // Grab the user-entered log-in data
  $user_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($_POST['username']));
  $user_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($_POST['password']));

  if (!empty($user_username) && !empty($user_password)) {
    // Look up the username and password in the database
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName = '$user_username' AND UserPassword = SHA('$user_password')";
    $data = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) {
      // The log-in is OK so set the user ID and username session vars (and cookies), and redirect to the home page
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
      $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['UserID'];
      $_SESSION['username'] = $row['UserName'];
      setcookie('user_id', $row['UserID'], time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30));    // expires in 30 days
      setcookie('username', $row['UserName'], time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30));  // expires in 30 days
      $user_role = $row['UserRole'];
      $_SESSION['user_role'] = $row['UserRole'];
      setcookie('user_role', $row['UserRole'], time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30));  // expires in 30 days
      $_SESSION['user_group'] = $row['UserGroup'];
      setcookie('user_group', $row['UserGroup'], time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30));  // expires in 30 days
        If ($user_role=='DM')
            header('Location: DMView.php');
        else
            header('Location: VendorView.php');
    }
    else {
      // The username/password are incorrect so set an error message
      $error_msg = 'Sorry, you must enter a valid username and password to log in.';
    }
  }
  else {
    // The username/password weren't entered so set an error message
    $error_msg = 'Sorry, you must enter your username and password to log in.';
  }
}
```

My checkUser file:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) 
{
    session_start();
}
  // If the session vars aren't set, try to set them with a cookie
  if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
if (isset($_COOKIE['user_id']) && isset($_COOKIE['username'])) {
  $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_COOKIE['user_id'];
  $_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['username'];
  $_SESSION['user_role']=$_COOKIE['user_role'];
  $_SESSION['user_group'] = $_COOKIE['user_group'];
}
 }

   if ((!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) )  {
echo '<p>Please <a href="index.php">log in</a> to access this page.</p>';

exit();}
```

and my Logout file:

```
// If the user is logged in, delete the session vars to log them out
  session_start();
  if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
// Delete the session vars by clearing the $_SESSION array
$_SESSION = array();

    // Delete the session cookie by setting its expiration to an hour ago (3600)
if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
  setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 3600);
}

    // Destroy the session
session_destroy();
  }
    // Delete the user ID and username cookies by setting their expirations to an hour ago (3600)
  setcookie('user_id', '', time() - 3600);
  setcookie('username', '', time() - 3600);

  // Redirect to the home page

 header('location: index.php');
```

The submit file (simplified with only one query):

```
<?php
require('connection.php');
require ('checkUser.php');


$task=$_POST['task_id'];
$row=$_POST['row_id'];
if( $_POST['answer']==1 )
{
    $query="UPDATE ecnmatchingdetails SET RowStatus=2,Agent='".$uName."' , VendorAnswer='Yes', VendorComment='".$_POST['comments']."' , end_tag='".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' where TaskID=".$task." and RowId=".$row;
    mysqli_query($con, $query);
}
else...
}

if( isset( $_POST['answer'])) {
    header( 'Location: http://dub-entas-124/tool/TT/WorkOnTask.php?id='.$task . '&start_task=0&prevID='.$Ebay_PRD_ID);
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: how you are checking session WorkOnTask.php?

Comment: I included "checkUser" in all my files including "initial" and "WorkOnTask"

Comment: Are you using Google Chrome? If so try to see the behavior on other browsers like Firefox or IE or Safari! Check if the problem consists. I have been having a similar issue only on Chrome Browsers

Answer (score 1):

If I guess your question correct,
You are registering cookie and in same page you are checking, being cookie stored in client side, it will be available only after reload or on another page...

Comment: Can you please explain? Why it can be the reason for the first login not to work but for the second one to work? I am including "checkUser.php" in the main view and in the tag view but the logout occurs only after the submit (instead of going to the update.php)

Comment: By the way, i have checked my PHP version and it is 5.4.7

Comment: so problem may be in submit page or "next page"

Comment: I have added the submit page... I dont see a problem there but the main issue is how come there is a problem in the FIRST login after logout but there is no problem in the second login? What is the difference?

Comment: check your code anywhere you unset the cookies or destroy session unneccessary on your submit/next page.

Comment: I do it only in the logout. Also, if i had unset cookies then it would log out each time, no? What makes the first time special?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue for a while and looked everywhere.

All I did to fix this was change this in my php.ini

```
session.cookie_domain = ".example.com"
```

Put this before the session_start() which should be at the very top of your PHP

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com' );
session_start();
```